# Javascript - error callback is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, assincronismo, callback

Eu estou a executar umas **funções assíncronas**, que recebem uma **callback**, essa callback recebe como **parâmetro um boolean(true or false)**.
Ao executar tenho o erro **callback is not defined**.

[código]

file - app.js

```
session.checkip(req.ip, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

file - session.js

```
exports.checkip = function(ip, callback) {
  var r = false;
  let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '***********',
    database: 'website_personal_trainer'
  });

  connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
      }

      console.log('Connected to the MySQL server. checkip');
    });

  connection.query('select * from session', function(err, result, fields){
    for (var i in result)
        if (result[i].ip == ip) {
            r = true;
            break;
        }
    connection.end(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log('error:' + err.message);
      }
      console.log('Close the database connection.');
      callback(r);
    });
  });
```

[Debuging]
Quando altero o parâmetro para receber strings, a função executa normalmente.
Podem ajudar-me?

**[update] - 23/02/2019**
O código apresentado, funciona corretamente. Após ter encontrado uma solução alternativa para o que queria fazer, voltei a testar este mesmo código e não obtive qualquer erro. Daí concluir, que o erro obtido anteriormente não tenha haver com este código apresentado.

Comment: Acho que esse erro não está no código que tens na pergunta.

Comment: A função `callback` não existe no contexto em que ela foi chamada, dentro de outro callback. `---> callback(r)`, neste caso, você pode corrigir redeclarando a variável: `var callback = callback` logo abaixo de `exports.checkip = function(ip, callback) {`

Comment: @edsonalves não consegui perceber. session.checkip não é uma callback. Poderia explicar o seu raciocínio pf.

Comment: Você recebe um callback Nessa função e tenta chamar ele dentro de outro callback. Este outro não consegue enxergar a função recebida em forma de variável e dá este erro, redeclarando o a variável ele passa a enxergar

Answer (score 2):

Fiz uns ajustes no código pra garantir a chamada da função de callback independente dos erros ou não, também adicionei um parâmetro nela para validar erros, e alterei o *for* por um *filter*.

```
exports.checkip = function (ip, callback) {

    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'Escola171995',
        database: 'website_personal_trainer'
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) return callback('error:' + err.message, false);
    });

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM session', function (err, result, fields) {

        let sessionIp = result.filter(session => session.ip == ip);

        connection.end(function (err) {
            if (err) return callback('error:' + err.message, false);

            if (sessionIp.length > 0){
                callback(true, 'Close the database connection.');
            }else{
                callback(false, 'Not Close the database connection.');
            }

        });
    });
}

session.checkip(req.ip, function(err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Acredito que esse ajustes vão lhe ajudar.

Sobre o problema de undefined no callback, acredito que seja pela função não ter sido executada por causa da chamada do return

Comment: Pedro, outra coisa que pode ajudar é fazer a query no banco usando o where e resolvendo a filtragem do dado no banco de dados, algo do tipo: "SELECT * FROM session WHERE session.ip = ?" passando o IP como parâmetro da query.

Comment: Qual era o problema original no código que motivava o _"callback is not defined"_?

Comment: @Sergio o erro original é que se usar argumentos do tipo boolean(ou seja, a função callback usa result type boolean) tenho o erro callback is not defined. Quando uso strings a representar booleans(ou seja, 'true' ou 'false') o código corre perfeitamente.

Comment: @fabioxd20 eu apercebi-me disso antes de ver sua resposta, tem toda a razão. Um filter também seria uma boa opção. No entanto essa query com o WHERE foi utilizada como melhoramento do código.

Comment: @PedroCorreia o que escreves não faz sentido. O erro que seria lógico é `callback is not a function`, se diz que é `undefined` isso é outro tipo de problema.

Comment: @Sergio basicamente a ideia é a seguinte https://jsfiddle.net/hyuv0eq3/4/, é só por a minha myFunction no caso atual estar num ficheiro que é importado. Mas como te disse, trocando booleans para strings funciona. Neste exemplo de código que te mostrei funciona para ambos, daí eu compreender a tua dúvida.

Comment: @sérgio tens razão o erro que tive na altura não tinha haver com isso, confusão minha. Porque agora voltei a testar após já ter arranjado uma solução alternativa e funciona corretamente para todos os tipos(inclusive booleans). Podes me aconselhar, não sei dar seguimento ao tópico. Deverei apagar?

Comment: Não será por eu ter feito, no connection.end() return console.log();?

Comment: @PedroCorreia o mais importante é aprendermos a programar melhor e partilhar com outros. Se quiseres podes dar uma resposta, apagar a pergunta ou pedir ao abioxd20 que adapte a resposta.

Comment: Exato! Quando você deu return na função que esperava o callback você não executou a função, acredito que esse seja o motivo também

Answer (score 0):

Ele retorna o valor e nao está recebendo o valor dentro do for loop. Por tanto, quando voce coloca uma string no var r o calback envia o valor inicial da variavel e nao o vALO MODIFICADO NO FOR LOOP. UMA SOLUÇAO:

connection.query('select * from session', function(err, result, fields){

```
let count = 0;

let limit =result.length;

for (var i in result)

    if (result[i].ip == ip) {

        r = true;

        break;
    }

  count++;

if(count == limit) {


connection.end(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log('error:' + err.message);
    }
    console.log('Close the database connection.');
    callback(r);
 });
```

}

Comment: O "connetion.end()" só executa após o ciclo "for" ter terminado, por isso não é por aí.